# Listening for a TCP connection in IOS 6

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, tcp, ios6

I am writing a client-server application for IOS6. I need to send simple messages from multiple iPhones to a single iPad. I have managed to get the send functions to work on the iPhone by using **CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost**, by pointing to a realbasic application on the mac I see the messages.

I need to set up a socket to listen on a specific port on the iPad but seem to be having problems finding info and examples on this!

Does anyone have any simple examples of listening and reading sockets on IOS6?

Comment: Robbie Hanson's [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) works well on OSX and iOS for both server and client. There are some examples available in the download.

Comment: Check : 
Ray Wanderlich tutorial : <a href="http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server">How to Create a Socked Based iPhone App and Server</a>.
I've used it to a project with 2 sockets on two different ports.